# SSAS - Need to have a calculated member that uses as a denominator one particular dimension value

Tags: ssas, mdx, member

I have a cube that I built in SSAS for general ledger data.  The cube uses 2 fact tables.  One for accounts that are "normal" dollar based accounts and the other is for unit / statistical accounts - accounts that count ANYTHING, except for money usually.

I need for one calculated member in SSAS to be ANY of the "normal" dollar based accounts divided by ONLY one particular dimension of the statistical accounts.

If clear as mud - let me give the specific example.  There is an statistical account called Gallons (measure is units) and there are many accounts such as sales, depreciation, tax expense, etc that are the "normal" G/L accounts (measure in dollars).  I need to have the cube be able to report on ANY of the "normal" G/L accounts DIVIDED by Gallons (so that any of the normal revenue / expense accounts can have a measure that shows BY GALLON.)

I have no clue how to write the MDX to do this (the function to use and / or the syntax) and I have tried many times and researched quite a bit (I am a SQL person - FAR from a MDX person I guess!).  I'm thinking I need to use FILTER but I'm not even sure that is the right direction.....

Answer (score 0):

Little unsure with your design ,If you are having trouble with MDX you can create a calculated member in DSV using T-sql

Comment: Thank you paranjai.  I know of and have created calculated members that way.  I ended up resolving this issue a totally different way.  I'm going to see / if I can revoke this question so I don't waste other's time.  Thanks again.